# Background location update in Android periodically

Tags: android, google-location-services

I am Using Fused Location Provider Google api client to get the location for every 5 minutes . It is updating both in background and also when the application is killed . But it is Stopped updating after some 2 to 3 days . i have tested in most of the android devices.

I am calling this Service from an Activity and i am Killing the application, it is sending location updates for every 5 minutes for almost 3 days after that it is getting stopped .I tried So many times.

```
public class GPSTracker extends Service implements
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener {

    protected static final String TAG = "Location...";
    private Context mContext = this;


    /**
     * Tracks the status of the location updates request.
     */
    public static Boolean mRequestingLocationUpdates;
    /**
     * Time when the location was updated represented as a String.
     */
    protected String mLastUpdateTime;
    /**
     * Provides the entry point to Google Play services.
     */
    protected GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    /**
     * Stores parameters for requests to the FusedLocationProviderApi.
     */
    protected LocationRequest mLocationRequest;

    /**
     * Represents a geographical location.
     */
    protected Location mCurrentLocation;
    public static boolean isEnded = false;


    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        buildGoogleApiClient();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }


    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        Log.d("LOC", "Service init...");
        isEnded = false;
        mRequestingLocationUpdates = false;
        mLastUpdateTime = "";
        // buildGoogleApiClient();
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected() && mRequestingLocationUpdates) {
            startLocationUpdates();
        }
        return START_STICKY;
    }




    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {

        startLocationUpdates();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        // The connection to Google Play services was lost for some reason. We call connect() to
        // attempt to re-establish the connection.
        Log.i(TAG, "Connection suspended==");
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        mCurrentLocation = location;
        mLastUpdateTime = DateFormat.getTimeInstance().format(new Date());
        double latitude = location.getLatitude();
        double longitude = location.getLongitude();

        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        StringBuilder latlong = stringBuilder.append(latitude + "," + longitude);

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        String zone = TimeZone.getDefault().getDisplayName(false, android.icu.util.TimeZone.SHORT);
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM 'at' h:mm a");
        Date date = new Date();
        String localtime = (formatter.format(date)).toString();

        Date myDate = new Date();

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
        calendar.setTime(myDate);
        date = calendar.getTime();
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss zz");
        dateFormatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
        String utc = dateFormatter.format(date);

      //  DateFormat df = DateFormat.getTimeInstance();
      //  df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("gmt"));
      //  String gmtTime = df.format(new Date());

        String model = Build.MODEL;

        String reqString = Build.VERSION.RELEASE
                + " " + Build.VERSION_CODES.class.getFields()[android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT].getName();

        // Date currentTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
        // String localtime = currentTime.toString();

        PreferencesClass preferencesClass = new PreferencesClass(mContext);
        String id = preferencesClass.getFingerPrint();

        Data data = null;
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
            jsonObject.put("userId", id);
            jsonObject.put("latLon", latlong);
            jsonObject.put("timeZone", zone);
            jsonObject.put("localTime", localtime);
            jsonObject.put("osVersion",reqString);
            jsonObject.put("phoneModel",model);
            jsonObject.put("utcTime",utc);
            data = new Data();
            data.setData(jsonObject.toString());

            if (data != null) {

                if (Utility.isConnectingToInternet(mContext)) {

                   // boolean isChecked = preferencesClass.getIsChecked();
                  //  if (isChecked){

                        LocationWebServiceMgr locationWebServiceMgr = new LocationWebServiceMgr();
                        locationWebServiceMgr.Location(data, new CallBackInterface() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(ArrayList<Object> objects, ResponseMetaData responseMetaData) {

                                Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: Succesfully added the location to server");
                                // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "added to server", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(ResponseMetaData t) {
                            }
                        });

                   // } else {
                     //   Log.d("serverCall", "Location Permission not available ");

                  //  }

                } else {

                    Log.e("serverCall", "Network not available");

                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        // Refer to the javadoc for ConnectionResult to see what error codes might be returned in
        // onConnectionFailed.
        Log.i(TAG, "Connection failed: ConnectionResult.getErrorCode() = " + connectionResult.getErrorCode());
    }

    /**
     * Builds a GoogleApiClient. Uses the {@code #addApi} method to request the
     * LocationServices API.
     */
    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        Log.i(TAG, "Building GoogleApiClient===");
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();

        createLocationRequest();
    }

    /**
     * Sets up the location request. Android has two location request settings:
     * {@code ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION} and {@code ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}. These settings control
     * the accuracy of the current location. This sample uses ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, as defined in
     * the AndroidManifest.xml.
     * <p/>
     * When the ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION setting is specified, combined with a fast update
     * interval (5 seconds), the Fused Location Provider API returns location updates that are
     * accurate to within a few feet.
     * <p/>
     * These settings are appropriate for mapping applications that show real-time location
     * updates.
     */
    protected void createLocationRequest() {
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();

        // Sets the desired interval for active location updates. This interval is
        // inexact. You may not receive updates at all if no location sources are available, or
        // you may receive them slower than requested. You may also receive updates faster than
        // requested if other applications are requesting location at a faster interval.
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(Constants.UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS);

        // Sets the fastest rate for active location updates. This interval is exact, and your
        // application will never receive updates faster than this value.
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(Constants.FASTEST_UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS);

       // mLocationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(Constants.DISPLACEMENT);

        //mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    }

    /**
     * Requests location updates from the FusedLocationApi.
     */
    protected void startLocationUpdates() {
        if (!mRequestingLocationUpdates) {
            mRequestingLocationUpdates = true;

            // The final argument to {@code requestLocationUpdates()} is a LocationListener
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // TODO: Consider calling
                //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                //                                          int[] grantResults)
                // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                return;
            }
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
                    mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
            Log.i(TAG, " startLocationUpdates===");
            isEnded = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please edit the question to add the code where the Location is getting updated in the background to provide more context.

Answer (score 0):

you can create service for do this

```
public class TimeService extends Service {
    // constant
    public static final long NOTIFY_INTERVAL = 10 * 1000; // 10 seconds

    // run on another Thread to avoid crash
    private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    // timer handling
    private Timer mTimer = null;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        // cancel if already existed
        if(mTimer != null) {
            mTimer.cancel();
        } else {
            // recreate new
            mTimer = new Timer();
        }
        // schedule task
        mTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimeDisplayTimerTask(), 0, NOTIFY_INTERVAL);
    }

    class TimeDisplayTimerTask extends TimerTask {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // run on another thread
            mHandler.post(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // display toast
                   startService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
                }

            });
        }

        private String getDateTime() {
            // get date time in custom format
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("[yyyy/MM/dd - HH:mm:ss]");
            return sdf.format(new Date());
        }

    }
```

and service for location

```
public class MyService extends Service
{
    private static final String TAG = "BOOMBOOMTESTGPS";
    private LocationManager mLocationManager = null;
    private static final int LOCATION_INTERVAL = 1000;
    private static final float LOCATION_DISTANCE = 10f;

    private class LocationListener implements android.location.LocationListener
    {
        Location mLastLocation;

        public LocationListener(String provider)
        {
            Log.e(TAG, "LocationListener " + provider);
            mLastLocation = new Location(provider);
        }

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
        {
            Log.e(TAG, "onLocationChanged: " + location);
            mLastLocation.set(location);
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider)
        {
            Log.e(TAG, "onProviderDisabled: " + provider);
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider)
        {
            Log.e(TAG, "onProviderEnabled: " + provider);
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras)
        {
            Log.e(TAG, "onStatusChanged: " + provider);
        }
    }

    LocationListener[] mLocationListeners = new LocationListener[] {
            new LocationListener(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER),
            new LocationListener(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)
    };

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0)
    {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "onStartCommand");
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "onCreate");
        initializeLocationManager();
        try {
            mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                    LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, LOCATION_INTERVAL, LOCATION_DISTANCE,
                    mLocationListeners[1]);
        } catch (java.lang.SecurityException ex) {
            Log.i(TAG, "fail to request location update, ignore", ex);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
            Log.d(TAG, "network provider does not exist, " + ex.getMessage());
        }
        try {
            mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                    LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, LOCATION_INTERVAL, LOCATION_DISTANCE,
                    mLocationListeners[0]);
        } catch (java.lang.SecurityException ex) {
            Log.i(TAG, "fail to request location update, ignore", ex);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
            Log.d(TAG, "gps provider does not exist " + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "onDestroy");
        super.onDestroy();
        if (mLocationManager != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < mLocationListeners.length; i++) {
                try {
                    mLocationManager.removeUpdates(mLocationListeners[i]);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "fail to remove location listners, ignore", ex);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void initializeLocationManager() {
        Log.e(TAG, "initializeLocationManager");
        if (mLocationManager == null) {
            mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am calling this Time service from an Activity , it is updating when the application is in background . But it it not updating when the application is killed.

Comment: start service in application class

Comment: The control is coming to MyService OnStart method for every 5 minutes but the control is not comming to OnLocatioChanged  method

Comment: you can easily put timer to MyService  class for control listener

Comment: I am so sorry that i am not able to solve this . I am very new to android. Can u please help me in solving this problem.

Comment: see this link https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/os/handler/android-timer-example/

Answer (score 0):

Use workmanager to reschedule your location service. Check if location service not running then start from scheduler.
To read more regarding workmanager [click here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/basics)

Answer (score -1):

For that, you can use [**AlarmManager**](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html) or [**firebase jobdispatcher**](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-jobdispatcher-android) or [**job scheduler**](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/scheduling.html) to trigger any event after specific intervals. I suggest you to use **AlarmManager** which are easiest.

**Refer this code to set alarm:**

```
  Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
  calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
  int notificationID = 2018;

 AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
 Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
 PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, notificationID, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
 alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),5*1000, pendingIntent);
```

And you can **cancel alarm** like this way:

```
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, notificationID, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
    pendingIntent.cancel();
```

**Note:** Beginning with API 19 (KITKAT) alarm delivery is inexact: the OS will shift alarms in order to minimize wakeups and battery use. There are new APIs to support applications which need strict delivery guarantees; see setWindow(int, long, long, PendingIntent) and setExact(int, long, PendingIntent). Applications whose targetSdkVersion is earlier than API 19 will continue to see the previous behavior in which all alarms are delivered exactly when requested.

Comment: I tried calling alarm manager from activity , but it is not calling when the application is killed. If i have to call alarm manager from service , in which method i should call.

Comment: @TimCastelijns, Google doesn't deprected AlarmManager still now. We can use it to trigger event any specific intervals..please [refer this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) and when google remove that method, none will use it.

Comment: @TimCastelijns, Is there any other option to trigger any event at **specific time in background process**?

Comment: stop pinging me

Comment: @TimCastelijns, I am not pinging you but you should give proper answer for this question.

Comment: you **are** pinging me. I'm not obliged to answer your questions and I'm not going to

Comment: @Nethra, If this answer is useful then please mark this answer as right

Answer (score -1):

Create a class for location get.

```
 private class LocationListener implements android.location.LocationListener
{
    Location mLastLocation;

    public LocationListener(String provider)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "LocationListener " + provider);
        mLastLocation = new Location(provider);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "onLocationChanged: " + location);
        mLastLocation.set(location);
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "onProviderDisabled: " + provider);
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "onProviderEnabled: " + provider);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "onStatusChanged: " + provider);
    }
}
```

in onLocation(Location location) change method you will get current let,long